# Select td using an id then add a class and remove classes

Tags: html, jquery, css-selectors

I have an html table that has navigation links in it.  When you hover over a link I am able to modify the background color and color of the link text.  I want to do something similar for active links.  I've been trying to do this with jQuery.  I've selected the td that the link is in using the id and then I add the class to the td.  Nothing seems to change or work.  Below is my html and below that is my JavaScript.  Please show me the error of my ways.

```js
$(function() {
  var links = ['1', '2', '3'];
  $("a").click(function() {
    $.each(links, function(index, value) {
      $("#" + value).removeClass('link-active-td');
      $("#" + value + 'td').removeClass('link-active-td');
    });
    var linkid = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#" + linkid).addClass('link-active-td');
    $("#" + linkid + 'td').addClass('link-active-text');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1">
      <a class="a-nav" id="1td" href="..." ?>
        <div>
          First Anchor Text
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td id="2">
      <a class="a-nav" id="2td" href="..." ?>
        <div>
          Second Anchor Text
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td id="3">
      <a class="a-nav" id="3td" href="..." ?>
        <div>
          Second Anchor Text
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is the front end for a python django project.

Comment: Probably an issue with the td having an id that starts with a number

Comment: Also this logic could be simplified if you added a common class to the tds, and used the class on the links, for the class removal part.

Comment: Also, you don't need to grab the id off of the link to find it. `this` **is** the link.  And `$(this).closest('td')` is it's parent td.

Comment: Instead of the `each` can simply do `$('.link-active-td').removeClass('link-active-td')`. With repeating elements using ID selectors is typically more work than it's worth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:
I have updated script.

Explantion:

To add class to `td` you have use `parent()` selecter like  `$("#" + linkid).parent().addClass('link-active-text');`

You can remove class by directly using below code

```
$('.link-active-td').removeClass('link-active-td');
$('.link-active-text').removeClass('link-active-text');
```

Here is full code:

```js
$(function() {
 
  $("a").click(function() {
    
    $('.link-active-td').removeClass('link-active-td');
    $('.link-active-text').removeClass('link-active-text');
    var linkid = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#" + linkid).addClass('link-active-td');
    $("#" + linkid).parent().addClass('link-active-text');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1">
      <a class="a-nav" id="1td" href="#">
        <div>
          First Anchor Text
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td id="2">
      <a class="a-nav" id="2td" href="#">
        <div>
          Second Anchor Text
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td id="3">
      <a class="a-nav" id="3td" href="#">
        <div>
          Second Anchor Text
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Explain what you did and why it helps. People shouldn't have to compare every line of this to the original and look for differences

Comment: Ohh sorry, I have updated  $("#" + linkid + 'td').addClass('link-active-text'); with  $("#" + linkid + 'td').addClass('link-active-td');

Comment: So edit the answer to explain it. Code only answers are not very helpful

Comment: Might also mention that OP is trying to remove a different class from `td` than what they add

Comment: This looks like what I submitted except you got the class names wrong.

Comment: @user2547177 I have updated script, it's working for me. Please check

Comment: You still haven't updated your answer to explain how this works. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Comment: I thank you for the answer and I've added this to my code, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Have you applied your styling for that classes?

Comment: What do you mean?  When I add those classes to the dom through Chrome, it works.

Comment: Also var linkid = $(this).attr("id") returns undefined.  That's why nothing works.

Comment: Can you please try $(this).prop('id')